# is the best way to regrouping the results and counting them from queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

this is my results from my queryset after grouping, i  want to regrouping the same value of times and then counting the totals,

```
<QuerySet [{'times': 5, 'total': 1}, {'times': 60, 'total': 1}, {'times': 60, 'total': 1}, {'times': 55, 'total': 1}, {'times': 55, 'total': 1}, {'times': 50, 'total': 1}, {'times': 50, 'total': 1}, {'times': 45, 'total': 1}, {'times': 40, 'total': 2}, {'times': 30, 'total': 1}, {'times': 25, 'total': 1}, {'times': 25, 'total': 1}, {'times': 25, 'total': 1}, {'times': 20, 'total': 1}, {'times': 15, 'total': 1}, {'times': 15, 'total': 1}, {'times': 15, 'total': 2}, {'times': 15, 'total': 1}]>
```

i've tried using *for in* but actually didn't work properly, using Counter

unhashable type: 'slice',
indices type , etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import itertools
import operator

f = lambda x:x['times']
[{'times':k, 'total': sum(map(operator.itemgetter('total'), g))}
  for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)]
```

Output:

```
[{'times': 5, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 15, 'total': 5},
 {'times': 20, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 25, 'total': 3},
 {'times': 30, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 40, 'total': 2},
 {'times': 45, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 50, 'total': 2},
 {'times': 55, 'total': 2},
 {'times': 60, 'total': 2}]
```

Explain of `{'times':k, 'total': sum(map(operator.itemgetter('total'), g))}`:

- `itertools.groupby` returns iterable `(group_keys, groups)`.
- `map`ing `operator.itemgetter('total')` to `g` is same as `[d['total'] for d in g]`, i.e. get all `total`s from all the `dict`s that belong to the same group.
- And finally, make new `dict` for each group

Comment: name 'l' is not defined in `sorted(l, key=f), key=f)`  what l is supposed to ?

Comment: @FajrullahSejatiEvat My bad. It is the query set you have :)

Comment: the code work fine, thank you, 
can you explain `[{code..} for k, g in ...`
acording to your answer , can you explain about **code** left side `for` what is purpose ?

Comment: @FajrullahSejatiEvat Updated the answer. Please let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(int)

for d in mylist:
    d_dict[d['times']] += d['total']

[{'times':i[0],'total':i[1]} for i in d_dict.items()]
```

Result:

```
[{'times': 5, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 15, 'total': 5},
 {'times': 20, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 25, 'total': 3},
 {'times': 30, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 40, 'total': 2},
 {'times': 45, 'total': 1},
 {'times': 50, 'total': 2},
 {'times': 55, 'total': 2},
 {'times': 60, 'total': 2}]
```

Comment: thank you, that work fine too , the code easly understand for newbie like me.